# Getting a parsing error in my React application

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am getting a parsing error when running my React app 
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Line 7:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

I have checked my code for any unexpected token and did not see any.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import './game.html';
    import Grid from './board.js';
    class App extends from React.Component {
        render(){
            return(
                     <div className="game-board">
                        <Grid/>
                     </div>
                  );
        }
    }
    export default App;


    import React from 'react';
    import Square from './square.js';
    class Grid extends React.Component{
        renderSquare(i)
        {
            return <Square value={i}/>
        }
        render(){
            <div className="gamerow">
                {this.renderSquare(1)}
                {this.renderSquare(2)}
                {this.renderSquare(3)}
            </div>
            <div className="gamerow">
                {this.renderSquare(4)}
                {this.renderSquare(5)}
                {this.renderSquare(6)}
            </div>
            <div className="gamerow">
                {this.renderSquare(7)}
                {this.renderSquare(8)}
                {this.renderSquare(9)}
            </div>
            }
    }
   export default Grid;


   import React from 'react';
  //import Grid  from './board.js
   class Square extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                      <button className= "square">{this.props.value} 
                      </button>
                  );
        }
   }
```

export default Square;
I am  expecting the program to render a 3 by 3 grid on the UI.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such keyword `from` when extending a class:

```
//                 v remove from
class App extends from React.Component` { ... }
```

Moreover, in `Grid` component, you need a `return` statement from `render` function, you can only render a single `ReactElement`, in this example I used `<React.Fragment/>` to group all `<div/>` elements.

```
class Grid extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
//    v <React.Fragment>
      <>
        <div className="gamerow">
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
        </div>
        <div className="gamerow">
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
        </div>
        <div className="gamerow">
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
          {this.renderSquare(9)}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea ty its the prettier :-(

Answer (score 1):

Problem in below line.

```
class App extends from React.Component {
```

It should be look like below

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

Also you have to `return` the render method of `Grid` component.

Hope this will help you!